# comparing string in database field

Tags: php, mysql

hello i have table with the column name id,receiver_id and many more now i want to fetch record in which sender_id is current_logged in user and receiver_id contains the current loggend in id.

means receiver_id contains the string of user_id separated with , now i want to check whether user_id there in receiver_id or not

suppose my id is `U112` and receiver_id contains string `U112,U123,U157` now how can i check

i tried as follow but fails

`$selDoc="SELECT * FROM documents WHERE sender_id='U112' OR 'U112' IN (receiver_id)  ORDER BY id DESC";`

Comment: you should probably normalise your schema.. this is going to be a full table scan

Comment: i cant change the field now i have to work with it only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str IN (str2)` is the same as `str == str2`.

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
FIND_IN_SET('U112', receiver_id)
```

Note: you should probably normalize your schema.. this is going to be a full table scan.

Comment: i cant change database because it already live and running on server

Comment: well, at some point you have to learn how to update a production database.. schemas aren't written in stone ;)

Comment: but i am not authorized to do that

Answer (score 0):

or you can use

```
receiver_id LIKE "% U112 %"
```

Comment: i thought that it is maybe fixed with 3 numbers after letter, sorry my bad :(

Answer (score 0):

This might work correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE sender_id in ('U112','U113','U113')
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE sender_id ='U112' and sender_id in ('U112','U113','U113')
```

Note: I worked on my own table and it worked perfectly.
Example:

```
select * from tbl_answers where ques_id in ('69','12','14')
select * from tbl_answers where ques_id = 69 and ques_id in ('69','12','14')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM documents WHERE (receiver_id LIKE '%,U112' OR receiver_id LIKE 'U112,%' OR receiver_id LIKE '%,U112,%' OR receiver_id LIKE 'U112')
```